# Python Logging - Use a pre-format message file with key/code

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I want to use Logging with a dictionary of message.

The logger have for example a formatters attached :

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

I want to have a file like this for example with a pre configuration format message:

```
ERROR-1234 : "The entity : {1} doesn't exist"
ERROR-4321 : "The client : {1} with the name {2} doesn't exist"
```

When I make the call maybe like that :

```
logger.error(ERROR-1234, "entity-1")
logger.error(ERROR-4321, "25", "John Smith")
```

And the result

```
2018-05-31 16:55:42,584 - Example - ERROR- The entity : entity-1 doesn't exist}
2018-05-31 16:55:42,584 - Example - ERROR- The client : 25 with the name John Smith doesn't exist}
```

Can we do this behaviour (like Log4J) with logging librairy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a module:

```
# my_error_messages.py
errors = {
    1234: "The entity : %s doesn't exist",
    4321: "The client : %s with the name %s doesn't exist",
}
```

In your code:

```
from my_error_messages import errors

logger.error(errors[4321], "25", "John Smith")
```

Comment: Awesome ! So easy ! Thanks ;)